# Usage of "cancel" and "cancel out"

Tags: verbs, word-usage

It seems that *cancel* and *cancel out* can be used in the same way. For example, *A cancels B* or *A cancels out B*. In which context is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cancel out* is a [Phrasal Verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/phrasal.html), extending the sense of the verb *cancel* with the completive aspectual sense of *out.*

Some other examples:

- *stress out* 'lose effective control of oneself under stress, and because of it'
- *wink out*  'be unable to stay awake any longer, no matter **how** interesting the conversation is, nor **how** pressing the social obligation to stay awake may be'
- *burn out*

  - [literal; of fires] 'cease burning, usu. by deprivation of fuel'
  - [metaphoric; of humans] l'ose effective motivation, usu. by deprivation of reward'

The *out* produces the complete cancellation sense, but that's also available with *cancel* alone since it can mean 'to delete'. This is especially true with a Reciprocal construction like *each other*.

All of the following, for example, are grammatical, and equivalent in meaning.

- *Each cancelled the other.*
- *Each cancelled the other out.*
- *Each cancelled out the other.*
- *They cancelled each other.*
- *They cancelled each other out.*
- *They cancelled out each other.*

As can be seen, [Phrasal Verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/phrasals.html) have interesting and complex syntax, especially the transitive ones.

Answer (score 17):

When two things cancel each other out it means they "neutralize" each other, resulting in "zero." An example of this would be a sound cancelled out by another sound with inverted phase; by combining such two sounds, they cancel each other out and no sound is audible - the result is zero.

On the other hand, when something cancels something else, one of the two elements of cancellation still remains "active" even after the process. A user can cancel a computer process, for example. The user doesn't "disappear" after it happens.

TL;DR:

If *A cancels B* = A remains existent, B becomes nonexistent.
If *A cancels out B* = A and B become nonexistent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does this also mean that one should always write "A and B cancel each other out" instead of "A and B cancel each other"?

Comment: Yes, I'd always say "cancel each other out" and never "cancel each other."

Comment: Though if you find a function that makes a computer user disappear, please let me know. That could come in very handy for the help desk folks.